# Transporting via an identity type when inducting along the higher inductive type $S^1$

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I am reading the HoTT book https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1198-geeccc59.pdf and my question is regarding page 281, where the book says:

> When $x$ varies along loop, we need to prove that:

$\sf refl_{base}\cdot ap_{\lambda x.x}(loop) = ap_{\lambda x.\mu(x,base)}(loop)\cdot refl_{base}$

I tried manupulating the definition of "a path lying over $\sf loop$" by myself, but I cannot get there. In particular, I do not know where does the $\sf ap$ stuff comes from. Any help please? Thank you!

p.s. If someone may point out an active site where we can ask about HoTT it will be great!

**EDIT**:

I think I can get it from 2.11.3. The statement is:
For $f,g:A\to B$, with $p: a =_A a'$ and $q : f(a) =_B g (a)$, we have 
$ transport^{x\mapsto f(x) = g(x)}(p,q) = (ap_fp)^{-1}\cdot q\cdot ap_gp$

We can take $A,B = S^1$, $f:x\mapsto\mu(x,base),g:id_{S^1}$,from the induction principle we want $transport^{x\mapsto \mu(x,base)= x}(loop,refl_{base}) = refl_{base}$. By the lemma,

$transport^{x\mapsto \mu(x,base)= x}(loop,refl_{base}) = ap_{x\mapsto\mu(x,base)}(loop)^{-1}\cdot (refl_{base})\cdot ap_{x\mapsto x}(loop)$

So our goal becomes:

$ap_{x\mapsto\mu(x,base)}(loop)^{-1}\cdot (refl_{base})\cdot ap_{x\mapsto x}(loop)= refl_{base}$

And rearranging yields what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a combination of Theorem 2.11.5 and Lemma 2.3.10.  I'm not sure whether it follows directly from those results, or whether it needs to be a separately proven lemma as suggested in the last sentence of section 2.11.

MSE is a fine place to ask questions about HoTT.  Another is the [hott-cafe](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hott-cafe) google group.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! And I think it is lemma 2.11.3 rather than 2.11.5, could you please help check if it is correct? I think I have basically got it from 2.11.3, I will edit my question soon for verifiying.

Comment: Yes, that looks right.